# Breakline for contour

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, contour, smoothing, breaklines

I am trying to generate a break line for generating contour. I have surveyed point data. I am using the river banks/HFl points as breakines. I created a new shape file and drew line along the HFl points( snapping right at the point for the polyline vertices that I am digitizing.

For this polyline to serve as a break line, does the new line created need to have points with elevation values at its vertices?

I simply used the polyline in the shape file as break line while generating TIn module, It didn't act as a break line. i checked the attribute table it have no z values.

I have attached the image. The magenta is the breakline I drew.

[image]